# If you meant to call the 'StringField' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists

Tags: python, flask

I have defined this class model here

```
client =  pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)

db = client["test"]
col = db["products"]  

class Product(col.Document):
    name = col.StringField()
    category= col.StringField()
```

But when I try to run the script it is keep throwing the error  **If you meant to call the 'StringField' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.**
What I am missing

Comment: What are you trying to do there?  `StringField` is a Flask method.  It isn't part of Mongo.

Comment: Trying to define a model of my collection

Comment: You have to use Flask's `MongoEngine` to create Flask models, and you'd use `db.StringField()`, not `col.StringField()`.  I'm not sure it works with existing collections, but I haven't tried that.